# how to increase text size of radio button in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to increase size of text of radio buttons. These radio buttons I have called in a javascript function.

```
function renderQuestion(){
    test = _("test");
    if (pos >= questions.length) {
        test.innerHTML = "<h2>correct</h2>";
        _("test_status").innerHTML = "Quiz 1 Completed";
        pos = 0;
        correct = 0;
        return false;
    }

    _("test_status").innerHTML = "<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Question " + (pos + 1) + " of " + questions.length;
    question = questions[pos][0];
    chA = questions[pos][1];

    test.innerHTML = "<h3>" + question + "</h3>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'>" + chA + "<br>";// **need to increase the size of text**
    test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>NEXT</button>";
}
```

Comment: It's not clear exaclty what you're trying to do as radio buttons don't have any text. I can only assume you mean the related `<h3>` element, in which case just use CSS: `font-size: 18px` for example

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan he has a comment in his code where he wants the text size to increase, but it's hard to see unless you scroll right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this can be any help.

Please replace your line

```
test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'>" + chA + "<br>";
```

to

```
test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'><span style='font-size : 20px;'>" + chA + "</span><br>";
```

here `style='font-size : 20px;'` can be used to increase or decrease the font size you want

Comment: saying expected semicolon:

Comment: test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'><span style='font-size:20px'>" + chA + "</span><br>";

Answer (score 1):

You should add a label to your checkbox:

```
test.innerHTML += '<input type="radio" id="choices" name="choices" value="A"><label for="choices">' + chA + '</label><br>';
```

You can add a class to your label and simply increase its font-size via CSS.

Additionally a label with the `for=""` attribute will allow a click on the label to check the box with the same ID `id="choices"`.

*Note that I've changed the quotation marks. Since it's usually cleaner to leave the default `"` marks on HTML attributes. But this is just personal preference.*